# Content tagging Sitecore 9 and 10's: create Custom Folder Structures in Sitecore 9 and 10's TAP Repository for Bucket Management

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have been trying to implement an approach for a custom folder structure in the tap repository on buckets. In this approach, I have commented out the following line:

```
<!-- <setting name="BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath" value="yyyy\/MM\/dd\/HH\/mm"/> -->
```

in `Sitecore.Buckets.config` file. However, even after doing this, when I click on the tag button, the Sitecore tagging job runs and creates the same folders like `yyyy/MM/dd`.

[Bucket config] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8fw9.png)

[folder Structure] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PYf3.png)

If I disable the default `BucketFolderPath` setting, then we can implement the following setting:

```
 <setting name="BucketConfiguration.DynamicBucketFolderPath" value="Sitecore.Buckets.Util.BucketFolderPathResolver, Sitecore.Buckets"/>
```

`Sitecore.Buckets.config` file. By enabling this setting and using the `IDynamicBucketFolderPath` interface, we should be able to customize the folder structure.

In the `GetFolderPath` function and bucket rules, we can implement our own folder structure.

However, I'm still facing a blocker. Despite commenting out the `BucketFolderPath` setting, it still creates the same folders like `yyyy/MM/dd`. I have tried a lot, but I haven't found a solution yet. If anyone has any ideas or knows a way to disable this behavior, please let me know.

Ref URL: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/custom-bucket-structures.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if there are any other settings that might be overriding the BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath setting.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Sitecore falls back to the default value `yyyy\\/MM\\/dd\\/HH\\/mm` if the setting `BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath` is missing:

```
public class BucketConfigurationSettings
{
    public static string BucketFolderPath => Settings.GetSetting("BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath", "yyyy\\/MM\\/dd\\/HH\\/mm");
}
```

So commenting out this setting does not actually change anything because the same value is specified in the code by default.

[The preferred approach](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/custom-bucket-structures.html) for customising bucket folder structure is adding rules to the item `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings`, for example the rule below will create 3-level folder structure based on the first characters of item name:

[image: Rules for custom folder structure]

Please note that the setting `BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath` is only used if **no rules** are added to the item `Item Buckets Settings`. So if you keep the rules field empty, it is possible to modify the setting `BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath` via a config patch similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath" value="yyyy"/>      
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Value of this setting should either be a date format or a static string. If you replace it with an empty string, it will create a folder with the name "Repository" be default.

Hope this explains how bucket folder resolving works in Sitecore.